# Dynamic Link List RPG Inventory Program - Help (How do I link to classes ?)

Tags: c++, class, dynamic, linked-list, inventory

I'm making a class-based inventory system using two classes: one for characters and one for items.

> Code by Ryan Newell - NEW14136796 Uclan Student
>   (Need to put this in so plagarism monitors won't flag me for copying my own work)

Here's what I got so far.

```
    ///Code by Ryan Newell - NEW14136796 Runshaw College - Uclan
#include<iostream> //Base C++ required #
#include<string> //Allows input of strings
#include<iomanip>  //Base C++ required #
#include <conio.h> //Getchar error workaround
#include <cstdlib>  // Provides EXIT_SUCCESS
#include <fstream> // Allows output of txt files
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <Windows.h>//ConsoleSleep

using namespace std;

class itemspell{
    string itemname; //Name ((( what if items are the same name ? make difficult for finding statements ? maybe more char with same name item ?
    string itemtype; // Spell/Weapon/Armour/Magic Misc?
    string itemact; // What type of action does this item do ?
    string itemdesc; // Some random ingame description
    itemspell* inext; //The next pointer location


    bool isspell;   //Is Spell Boolean
    bool isweapon;  // Weapon
    bool isarmour; // So on so forth
    bool ismisc; // Misc
    bool offensiveitem; //Offensive item
    bool defensiveitem; // defensive item
    bool passiveitem; // Passive effect

    int damage;
    int armour;
    int magicbonus;
    int magicresistance;
    int cost;


    void item_spellsearch(itemspell* ihead, itemspell* &ipast, itemspell* &icurrent)
    {
        string search;
        if (ihead==NULL)
        {
            cout<<"There are no items on the list to search"<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Enter the type item you are searching for :"<<endl;
            getline(cin,search);
            icurrent=ihead; //current pointer goes to -> header
            cout<<icurrent<<" "<<search<<" "<<icurrent->itemtype<<endl; 
            while(icurrent!=NULL && search>icurrent->itemname)
            {
                cout<<"Item Type:"<<icurrent->itemtype<<" "<<cout<<icurrent->itemname<<endl;
                ipast=icurrent;  //Past = new current pointer
                icurrent=icurrent->inext; //current pointer = next pointer

            }
        }
    }
public:
    itemspell()//Building a new item // -- Cannot put byref / by values in here remember, needs to be default constructor for some reason ??
    {
        cout<<"Enter Item Type: "<<endl;
        getline(cin,itemtype);
        cout<<"Enter Item Name:  "<<endl;
        getline(cin,itemname);
        cout<<"Enter Item Description: "<<endl;
        getline(cin,itemdesc);
        cout<<"Enter Item Action :"<<endl;
        getline(cin,itemact);
    }

    ~itemspell()//Delete record output
    {
        cout<<"Item being deleted"<<endl;
        Sleep(500);
        cout<<"Item deleted"<<endl;
        getch();
    }


        void additemspell(itemspell* &ihead) // Add record code
        {
            itemspell *icurrent;
            itemspell *ipast;
            itemspell *newitem;

            newitem = new itemspell;  // New itemspell
            if (ihead == NULL || newitem->itemname<ihead->itemname) //If no header or itemname is null;
            {
                newitem->inext = ihead;
                ihead = newitem;
            }
            else
            {
                icurrent= ihead;
                while(icurrent !=NULL&&icurrent->itemname<newitem->itemname) // While the current char Does not equal NULL/"Nothing and charcurrent itemname = newitemitemname"
                {
                    ipast=icurrent;
                    icurrent=icurrent->inext;
                }
                newitem->inext=icurrent; // Sets the next char to current and the past char to next to add in new record.
                ipast->inext=newitem;
            }
        }

        void deleteitemspell(itemspell* &ihead) /// Getting the address of the itemspell not the itemspell itself
        {
            itemspell *ipast=NULL, *icurrent=NULL;
            item_spellsearch(ihead, ipast, icurrent);
            if(ihead!=NULL) 

            if(icurrent==NULL)
                {
                    cout<<"ERROR: No itemspell Found"<<endl;
                    Sleep(500);
                    cout<<"returning to menu... press enter"<<endl;
                    getch();
                }
            else
            {
                if (icurrent == ihead)
                {
                    ihead = ihead->inext;
                }
                else
                {
                    ipast->inext=icurrent->inext; //Resets the pointer and header's back to previous positions....

                    delete icurrent;// Calls the deletion of the itemspell entry.
                    cout<<"itemspell found was deleted press enter to confirm"<<endl;
                    getch();
                }
            }
        }


class character
{
    string forename;
    string surname;
    string nickname;
    string race;
    string alignment;
    string alignment_type;
    string character_class;
    int Strength; //Strength
    int Intelligence; //Magick 2
    int Willpower; //Magick 1
    int Endurance; //Health
    int Agility; //Agility
    int StartingWealth; //StartingWealth       
    character* char_itemp; // Character - Item pointer - Adress location of the characters items
    character* char_next; // Next Pointer Value- Points to the location of the next person in the Dynamic Linked List
```

What I'm trying to do is when I create a new item, I want to be able to give that item to a character to use.

I know somewhere along the lines of I need to create a pointer value in the character class to point to the itemspell class but I am unsure what to do and could do with some help.

Essentially I want to get the character class to point to the item class when the item class is called from the constructor within the item class.

Please, if you can, don't give just code. Rather, please highlight areas where I should change and give suggestion examples.  My degree program is strict about plagiarism.

---

Pseudo Code

```
When newitemspell created 
get input charactername ()
: 
if no current itemspell created for that character

  add item to 
 character->charactername
else      
 add item to next pointer character->charactername
```

[image]

Comment: @bearsmahoney if you want to take a look at this ?

Comment: A wall of code and a vague problem statement won't get you many answers. What have you tried so far? What issues did it cause? If the answer to the first is "nothing" then you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: @user657267 ive shortened it as much  as I can, and did you read the bottom ? - aside from that i've tried creating an array in the character class, ive tried making a public function to get the item in the character class, but I'm clueless on where to go from here.

Comment: If this is as short as the issue gets then it's probably off topic for SO, you might have more luck somewhere else. SO's preferred format is a precise problem with a precise solution, it sounds like you're asking about general software design which might be better suited for [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) or [gamedev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @user657267 the precise problem is how do I link 2 classes together ? so that when I declare a newitemclass it is stored somewhere in the character class.

Comment: Give your character class an `addItem` method.

Comment: @user657267 yeah but how do I link that to the current item ? :/ I have my points I assume im supposed to pass my points by val through the method ?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you mean by "link that to the current item". Try and express what you want to do in code, even pseudocode if you must, in the question itself.

Comment: @user657267 - this wouldn't be a good fit on Programmers either.  The OP is more interested in a pseudo-code based answer which implies it is an implementation issue and therefore off-topic for Progs.  And from my reading of it, you already addressed the conceptual aspects in an earlier comment of "Give your character class an `addItem` method."

Comment: @GlenH7 Thanks, I clearly don't visit programmers often enough to know what kind of questions are on-topic.

Comment: @user657267 - You may find this Meta.Progs post helpful:  http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7182/what-goes-on-programmers-se-a-guide-for-stack-overflow

Comment: I thought the question was clear enough to be honest @GlenH7 obviously im too stupid to understand. sorry....

Comment: @GlenH7 Im just running short on time and pretty desperate for an answer sorry.

Comment: You may want to let a 'Menu' handle the stuff, because , they are fictional characters. It may be too much work to define the characters as actually handling the items. The Menu may also be able to handle accounting and release of items... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at your code and looking at the descriptor of what you're trying to accomplish, why don't you just create an Inventory class to handle a users items? It should be able to handle 99% of anything you're wanting to do. Let me know if this example is anything like what you're trying to do.

To be completely honest, I have nary a clue what it is exactly you're trying to do in your code. As a previous user mentioned, "linking" two classes is a simple matter of giving the base class a variable of the required class. For example:

```
#include <vector> //I prefer to use vectors for just about any list of objects.
                  //It's just more convenient for me.
using std::vector;

class Inventory //A handler for all of your character's stuff.
{
private:
    vector<object_class> objs; //To actually store an array of whatever objects
                                //you need to.

//Just some example functions to make the class useful.
public:
   int MAX = -1; //The size limit for the inventory. This can be used as a useful
                 //statistic in the specific inventory, depending on how it's being
                 //used. My example shows the value at -1, which, at least for me,
                 //means that any maximum size checks being done won't bother it
                 //because I usually have a setting of -1 as being unlimited.

   getItem(int slot); //Return item
   removeItem(int slot) //Removing items
   addItem(object_class object) //Adding items
}
```

This is just really simple programming from here. All you need to do is create variables with the type of `Inventory`. Any reference to an `object_class` is just a generic fill-in for the class type of whatever object you're wanting the Inventory to handle. This will most likely be a base class while you're using derivatives.

```
class Character //The character class with all kinds of stuff to needs to be handled
{
public:
   Inventory items; //A regular inventory bag for items.
   Inventory equip; //The items the character is currently using.
   Inventory spells; //An alternate use for Inventory to be used as a handler for
                     //spell lists and other cool stuff.
}
```

And from here you should be able to understand what exactly is going on. Inventory isn't "linked" to Character. Character has three variables with the type Inventory and the Inventory class itself will handle all of the adding, removing, sorting and retrieving of items in its vector.

Now you can make everything work like so:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   Character player;
   Armor shield = new Armor(); //A dummy object
   player.items.addItem(shield); //Assuming the Inventory is setup to handle Armor items.
                                //This will add the shield to the player's inventory.
   player.items.MAX = 10; //Setting the maximum capacity of items to 10, obviously.
   Armor A = player.items.getItem(0); //returns the piece of armor in the first spot in the vector.
}
```

I would normally write way more modular code for something like this, such as making Inventory a template class, but I digress. This was just to show you how to attach one class object to another.

I hope this was remotely like what you were searching for. If not, please try rewriting your question a little more specifically.